# Как сделать чтобы при вводе команды писались все участники роли? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Например, пользователь пишет команду /team @blue и бот ему должен отправить список пользователей у которых есть данная роль, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Добрый день! Начинаю работать над вашим вопросом.

Comment: Есть какой-нибудь прогресс?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете попробовать что-то на подобии этого. Под ваш вопрос код нужно будет немного изменить, думаю для вас это не составит особой трудности :)

```
@client.command()
async def list(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    data = "\n".join([(member.name or member.nick) for member in role.members])
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Все участники с ролью {role}\n", description=f"{data}\n")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```